# Pour une partie du corps, peut-on remplacer le pronom personnel objet par un adjectif possessif ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, possessif

La page 105 de *Advanced French Grammar* de Véronique Mazet dit que:

> The definite article also follows any other verb, as long as the owner (of the body part) is obvious. Note that the owner is represented by the indirect object pronoun **lui** in the last two examples:
>
> 1. Il **lui** a coupé les cheveux = He cut his/her hair.
> 2. Le docteur **lui** a examiné la gorge = The doctor examined his/her throat.

Ma question : ces phrases sont-elles équivalentes à celles-ci :

1. Il a coupé ses cheveux.
2. Le docteur a examiné sa gorge.

Si non, pourquoi pas ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Le problème dans le fait de remplacer

> Il lui a coupé les cheveux.

par

> Il a coupé ses cheveux.

est que cela introduit une ambiguïté. Si la phrase est seule on peut penser (dans la version sans « lui ») que la personne coupe ses *propres* cheveux et non pas ceux de quelqu'un d'autre. En revanche si le contexte est clair il est possible d'écrire ces phrases de remplacements.

> Elle a demandé au coiffeur une coupe très courte et il a coupé ses cheveux.

Idem pour la seconde phrase, même si on se doute bien que sauf cas particulier le docteur ne va pas s'examiner lui-même.

> Elle est allée consulter pour une angine et le docteur a examiné sa gorge.

Comment: Merci beaucoup.